# Reading a list with multiple data types into "if else" statements

Tags: python, list, if-statement, types, iteration

I currently have this function I am working on (below):

```
def ThermoControl(datas):

    Accepted_Price = 13

    for data in datas:
        if Price > Accepted_Price:
            ac_on = False    #Heater Off
        elif weather == "cloudy":
            ac_on = False
        else:
            ac_on = True #Heater On
    return ac_on
```

I want the function to iterate through a list with two data types (integer and string) like the one below:

```
data = [[10, "cloudy"], [12, "sunny"], [9, "sunny"]]
```

The positions in the brackets correlate to [Price, weather]

Is there a way to have the function iterate through the list ("data") by checking each value in the pair and then moving on to the next index in the list?

If the function were to work with the aforementioned list, I would expect this output:

```
[False, True, True]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `ac_on` a list and append the the values for each data point. Access the the attributes of the tuples by index:

```
ac_on = []
for data in datas:
    if data[0] > Accepted_Price or data[1] == "cloudy":
        ac_on.append(False)
    else:
        ac_on.append(True)
return ac_on
```

Or as a shorter comprehension:

```
return [data[0] <= Accepted_Price and data[1] != "cloudy" for data in datas]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used print to show how output is generating.
I guess you are trying this only:

```
In [5]: data = [[10, "cloudy"], [12, "sunny"], [9, "sunny"]]
In [6]: def ThermoControl(datas):
   ...: 
   ...:     Accepted_Price = 13
   ...: 
   ...:     for Price, weather in data:
   ...:         if Price > Accepted_Price:
   ...:             ac_on = False    #Heater Off
   ...:         elif weather == "cloudy":
   ...:             ac_on = False
   ...:         else:
   ...:             ac_on = True #Heater On
   ...:         print(ac_on)
   ...: 

In [7]: ThermoControl(data)
False
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension implementation -

```
def ThermoControl(datas):
    Accepted_Price = 13
    return [ not (a[0]>Accepted_Price or a[1]=='cloudy') for a in data]

data = [[10, "cloudy"], [12, "sunny"], [9, "sunny"]]
print(ThermoControl(data))
```

Hope that helps!
Output - 
`[False, True, True]`